# Add global method to all Eloquent Models in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I want add given method to all my Eloquent Models:

```
public function isNew(){
    return $this->created_at->addWeek()->gt(Carbon::now());
}
```

Is this possible to do without bruteforce?

I could not find anything in the docs

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you can do:

1. Create `BaseModel` class and put all similar methods in it. Then extend this `BaseModel` class in all models instead of `Model` class:

`class Profile extends BaseModel`

2. Use [Global Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#global-scopes).
3. Create [trait](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) and use it in all or some of your models.

Comment: Thanks for the super quick response /T

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you can do that. Just simply extend the Laravel's eloquent model like so:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

abstract class BaseModel extends Model
{
    public function isNew() {
        return $this->created_at->copy()->addWeek()->gt(Carbon::now());
    }
}
```

Now your model should extend from this new `BaseModel` class instead:

```
class User extends BaseModel {
    //
}
```

This way you can do something like this:

```
User::find(1)->isNew()
```

Note that I also call `copy()` method on the `created_at` property. This way your `created_at` property would be copied and won't be accidentally added 1 week ahead.

```
// Copy an instance of created_at and add 1 week ahead.
$this->created_at->copy()->addWeek()
```

Hope this help.